# (VB.NET) 'VB6' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb6

I'm having a problem about accesibility of a class and that class is under a reference of "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility". I'm using 3.5 .NET FRAMEWORK by the way. Below is the error in my project. Can you help me guys?

Actually, I have two solutions in VB.NET. The one I being copied is running smoothly (no error in here) but in my project there's an error. Please check screenshots below.

Thanks Guys.

PS: BELOW IS MY CODE. (Not the entire module just only the procedure)

```
Public Sub m_splitBar_MouseDown(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles m_splitBar.MouseDown
    Dim Button As Short = eventArgs.Button \ &H100000
    Dim Shift As Short = System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys \ &H10000
    Dim X As Single = VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(eventArgs.X)
    Dim Y As Single = VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(eventArgs.Y)
    'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object m_bMoving. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
    m_bMoving = True
    splitterOnMove(m_splitBar)
End Sub
```

**ERROR:**
'VB6' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I cannot post an images guys, but see the links below.. They are the images that running and not running... I just need an advice why did this happening.

[Not running Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qiu7r3jyw0rdf40/not%20running.png?dl=0)

[Running Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihew738yj0fju0u/Running.png?dl=0)

Thanks Again xD

Comment: Please don't put your code in an image.  Post it as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks Eric for reminding me my code. ;) I hope you guys can help me. xD

Comment: Do you have `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility` somewhere at the top of that file?

Comment: Thanks, Ron Beyer.. it works... just follow up question.. Why in my Running Image (see top), it didn't have that "Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility" at the top of the page and it works?  WHY? Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PixelsToTwips is supported only in 32-bit projects. Try the following, or Use `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility`. Be sure to include Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility as a reference.

```
Dim X As Single = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(eventArgs.X)
Dim Y As Single = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(eventArgs.Y)
```

Comment: Thanks, xpda.. it works... just follow up question.. Why in my Running Image (see top), it didn't have that "Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility" at the top of the page and it works?  WHY? Can you explain?

Comment: I would guess it was automatically included somehow in the VB6 to .net conversion.